# How to keep the latest stable build for a given parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I have job with parameters and I want to keep the latest stable build for a given parameter.

Example

```
#1 run with param=A -> stable
#2 run with param=B -> stable
#3 run with param=A -> unstable
#4 run with param=B -> stable
#5 run with param=A -> unstable
```

I only keep 5 builds, and I want to keep always the latest stable build for a parmeter value. 
In my example, if the next build is still unstable, how to keep the job # 1, that is the last stable with the parameter A ?

I not find a plugin to do that.

How to define a preservation strategy that recognizes the value of a parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @Alex O for the plugin [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)

I am not familiar with the groovy and I am not be able to use the script that he proposed because it works not exactly as I wish. Or I don't have understood ...

And I wrote a different script that consider all builds stables and unstables. Perhaps it is not optimum but it work as I wish.

```
def allBuilds = manager.build.project.getBuilds()
def lastSuccessParamA = false
def lastSuccessParamB = false
def count = 0

for (hudson.model.Run run : allBuilds) {
    def param = run.buildVariables.get('param')
    if (lastSuccessParamA == false && run.result.isBetterOrEqualTo( hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS ) && "A".equals(param)) {
        manager.listener.logger.println( "keep last stable build with param = A : " + run)
        lastSuccessParamA = true
    } else if (lastSuccessParamB == false && run.result.isBetterOrEqualTo( hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS ) && "B".equals(param)) {
        manager.listener.logger.println( "keep last stable build with param = B : " + run)
        lastSuccessParamB = true
    } else if (count > 5){
        manager.listener.logger.println( "deleting build " + run)
        run.delete()
    } else {
        manager.listener.logger.println( "keep build " + run)
        count++
    }
}
```

Comment: Good that it works! I'm glad I could point you in the right direction : )

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: use the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) with the following script:

```
// get *all* the good builds first
def goodBuilds = manager.build.project.getBuilds().findAll { it.result.isBetterOrEqualTo( hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS ) }

// then remove all except for the first one
goodBuilds.drop( 1 ).each {
  manager.listener.logger.println( "deleting build " + it )
  it.delete()
}
```

That will ensure that only the last successful (stable) build remains in the build history.

**Step 2**: replace `goodBuilds.drop( 1 )` in the above script by some code that keeps the first build in `goodBuilds` *for any given parameter value*. This is left as an exercise :-)

On top of that, you can still set the limit on the total number of builds (5, in your case).

Comment: Thank for your answer, i will try it in few day

Comment: I retain the proposed plugin and I wrote another script.
Because in your script only stables builds are considered.
And I wish retain in 5 builds also the unstables